# Pandas: Merge two 1D DataFrames outputting both columns with fill-values for unique elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, join, merge

I have these two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,4,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,6]})


df1
Out[27]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  4
3  6

df2
Out[28]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  6
```

I want to merge them in a way that both columns are preserved, common values are joined disregarding their index and unique values get preserved with a fill-value in the other row, that is, I want this result:

```
   A_x  A_y
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  3.0
3  4.0  NaN
4  6.0  6.0
```

I have tried

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['A'],how='outer')
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,join='outer')
```

but those two don't yield the desired result. I've tried them with different options but no luck.

I also looked into other methods like `append` and `assign` but none seems to provide the functionality to do this.

I feel like this is a common operation that should have an easy straightforward solution, so I might be overlooking something obvious.

Can you tell me how it's done right?

Comment: it may not suit your needs, but if you want to keep both columns so you can compare and contrast the overlaps, you might be interested in the [`indicator` keyword argument](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for `merge`. It adds an annotated column that shows you whether the row existed in the left, right or both columns before merge.

Comment: That's valuable information, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) which concatenate values by `index`, so [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) is necessary:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('A', drop=False).A,
                df2.set_index('A', drop=False).A],
                axis=1, 
                keys=('A_x','A_y')).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   A_x  A_y
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  3.0
3  4.0  NaN
4  6.0  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a hunch about using `set_index()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
df2 = df2.set_index('A', drop=False)
kws = dict(on='A', lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y', how='outer')
df1.join(df2, **kws).drop('A', 1)

   A_x  A_y
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  4.0  NaN
3  6.0  6.0
3  NaN  3.0
```